# Ajax post is working in localhost but not in godaddy server

Tags: ajax

This ajax post is working in localhost but not in godaddy server. I dont know how to solve this kind of issues. Please let me know how rectify this issue.

Ajax is not working in many places. Locally all of files are working very fine.

I am new to php. Anyone can help me to fix this bug?

Thanks in Advance

```
function advanced_addTopic(cid) {    
      $.ajax({
            url: "assets/php/checkSubtopicStatus.php", // Url to which the request is send
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: {'cid':cid}, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields 
            success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
    {
                  if(data==="True"){
                        $("#subtopicDiv").html($("#subtopicDiv"+cid).html());
                    $("#advanced_testid").val(cid);

                var hiddenCourse=$("#createTest").attr('class');
                $("#courseHidden").val(hiddenCourse);
                   $("#advanced_addquestionModal").modal('show');
               $("#subtopic").focus();
               $("#question").focus();
                var tempVal=$("#getID").text(); 
                    $("#advanced_courseHidden").val(cid);
                } else {
                    alert("Create subtopics to insert questions!");
                }


      }
        });
```

My PHP CODE IS:

```
<?php 
 class loginValidation { 
function validate() 
   {
                ob_start();
                session_start();
                include "../../connection.php"; 
                $id=$_POST['cid'];

                $query = mysql_query("select * from advanced_subtopic where testid='$id'");
                if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
                        echo "True";    
                    } else {
                        echo "False";
                    }
            }}$loginValidation=new loginValidation;
            $loginValidation->validate();
```

?>

Comment: is your connection with db successful ?

Comment: Check the request being sent to the url and the url itself. Possibily the url could be wrong.

Comment: I think URL is correct because it is working fine in localhost.

Comment: Db connection is working properly @Muhamamd Usman

Comment: I think URL is correct because it is working fine in localhost. @KinshukLahiri

Comment: @srinivasan check console for any errors. Verify that the request is successful.

Comment: @KinshukLahiri - Request have been successful. But it returns false.

Comment: You are getting false in the response?

Comment: yes      
@KinshukLahiri

Comment: Add the code inside the question not here,

Comment: Hi !! @KinshukLahiri

Comment: @srinivasan You are using mysql that is deprecated and not the issue. There is something else. Please add a `print_r("here")` at the start so that you can see that the ajax is reaching the point.

Comment: Is this answer still active?

Answer (score 0):

Using Ajax URLs like

url: "http://domainname.com/assets/php/checkSubtopicStatus.php";

If you use your domain name HTTPS enter the same as an Ajax URL.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).